# Error "DocumentNotFoundError: No document found for query "{ _id:xxx}

Tags: node.js, mongoose, handlebars.js

I cloned the object "preventivo",
when I run this code I have the following error:
(node:24548) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): DocumentNotFoundError: No document found for query "{ _id: 5ff6110e27bbf25fe45ce2b5 }" on model "preventivi"
i can't understand the error, can you help me?
i use node + mongoose + handlebars
thanks

```
//ROUTE CLONA PREVENTIVO
app.post('/preventivi/dbpreventivi/:id/clone' ,accessoSicuro,(req , res) =>{
    Preventivi.findOne({
      _id: req.params.id
  })  
  .then(preventivo => {    
      var newdoc = new Preventivi(preventivo);
      newdoc._id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
      delete newdoc.__v;
      newdoc.save();
      console.log(newdoc._id)
     
      req.flash("msg_successo", "Preventivo clonato correttamente");
      res.redirect("/preventivi/dbpreventivi");
  });
});
//fine route clona preventivo
```

Html:

```
 <form  action="/preventivi/dbpreventivi/{{_id}}/clone?_method=POST" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST">
            <input onclick="return confirm('Vuoi clonare il preventivo: {{cliente}} {{codice}} ?');"  type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" value="Clona">
        </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try add newdoc.isNew = true :

```
//ROUTE CLONA PREVENTIVO
app.post('/preventivi/dbpreventivi/:id/clone' ,accessoSicuro,(req , res) =>{
    Preventivi.findOne({
      _id: req.params.id
  })  
  .then(preventivo => {    
      var newdoc = new Preventivi(preventivo);
      newdoc._id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
      newdoc.isNew = true;      
      newdoc.save();
      console.log(newdoc._id)     
      req.flash("msg_successo", "Preventivo clonato correttamente");
      res.redirect("/preventivi/dbpreventivi");
  });
});
//fine route clona preventivo
```

Answer (score 0):

Mine, was using "async map" incorrect way.
I did update some records in a "async map" method like below:

```
makerOrders.map(async makerOrder => {
....
    try {
      await Order.findByIdAndUpdate(makerOrder._id, {
        remainder: makerOrder.remainder,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(' order.save(); ' + err);
      return err(`Maker order is not updated. ${err}`, 500);
    }
...
  });
```

Even using try catch didn't catch the error and it has got 3 days to solve!

Hope help somebody :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I was not using session in `documentObject=model.create({...data})` query and using `documentObject.save({session})` in another query.
Since the document was not created using a specific session the document was not available in that session.